# Link text fields together on dynamic form

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code which allows me to dynamically add additional text fields when the button is pressed. I'm essentially mocking up multiple destinations along a route.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="form">
      <form id="address">
         <p>Route:</p>
         <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Origin">
         <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Destination">
         <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addField('address')">Add field</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function addField(id) {
          // OnClick function for adding additonal fields for
          // transit routes with multiple destinations.
          var field = `<br/><br/>
          <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Origin">
          <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Destination">`
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += field
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can fetch an array of all the elements within:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("address").elements;
```

But what I want to do is link every Destination field to the next Origin field, so that the Destination in the last field ends up as the Origin for the next row. I imagine it's something like below, but it's not clicking in my head.

```
elements[elements.indexOf(this)-1].value;
```

Comment: Instead of coding all this manually, have you considered using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), or a simple framework like [Knockout](https://knockoutjs.com/index.html)? (To say nothing of reactive frameworks.)

Comment: @9000 Frameworks have their uses, but in my view, they harm learning. I'm not savvy enough at this point to want to abstract away things. Thanks for the suggestions though.